# combobox disable edit and enable default selection c++ builder

Tags: combobox, c++builder, c++builder-6

I'm using combobox and I would like to disable user from edit,thus, I set ComboBox's Style property to csDropDownList and also I would like to set text field in order to enable default selection.
How can I do it?

(used in borland c++ builder bcb6)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: I tried changing text property but I can't since I used by csDropDownList style

Comment: you need to change `int ItemIndex` property ... -1 means no selection , 0,1,2,3,... are for the selection. If for some reason you need also restore text (sometimes different BCB behaves differently) then you need to also set the Text property to one from the `TStrings Items` ... (indexed by ItemIndex)

Comment: @Spektre: that should have been posted as an answer instead of a comment. Setting the `ItemIndex` property is the correct answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right moved to answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ItemIndex` property, where

- -1 means no item is selected
- 0, 1, 2, 3, etc will select an item at that index.

If, for some reason, you need to also restore text (sometimes different BCB versions behave differently) then you need to also set the `Text` property to one from the `TStrings Items` ... (indexed by `ItemIndex`).

Comment: I have been using BCB for almost 20 years and have never needed to save the `Text` property to restore a previous selection. Reading and later setting the `ItemIndex` property is enough.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had some issues with it in BCB5 but it could be some unrelated hidden bug somewhere on my side ... too long ago to remember